# eclipse - set position of view (or move view) programmatically

Tags: eclipse

Is there a possibility to set the relative position of a view in eclipse programmatically?
I know, that there is the function

*PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("org.eclipse.ease.ui.view.ModulesExplorerView");*

But I want to specify the relative position of this view, or move this view in a specified Position.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The position of the view is determined by any placeholder for the view in the current perspective. There is no other way to control where it is displayed.

There is some more information about this is the Eclipse Wiki [FAQ Why can't I control when, where, and how my view is presented?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_can%27t_I_control_when,_where,_and_how_my_view_is_presented%3F)

You can do it with Eclipse e4 - but this is a big design change and doesn't support all Eclipse 3.x code.